# How to change service type of well defined ports in SElinux (centOS 6.5)

Tags: centos, sshd, selinux

I need to be able to run SSH on port 23 instead of 22 on CentOS 6.5. **SElinux** won't allow that, as it has it as `tcp/23` defined in policy. Any steps on how can I go about changing service type from `telnetd_port_t` to `sshd_port_t`?

Comment: You can [use `semanage port`](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/practical-selinux-port-contexts-and-handling-access-alerts/) to change types.

Comment: semanage port does not change types of ports defined in policy of SELinux. Although I can use it to change service types of undefined ports

Answer (score 1):

Bratchley was on the right track.  Indeed 'semanage' can change (modify) already defined ports.

Here's a way that worked for myself:

```
[root@host ~]# semanage port -l |grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      22
[root@host ~]# semanage port -m -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 23
[root@host ~]# semanage port -l |grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      23, 22
```

From here, you can modify SSHD to listen/use port 23 in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, restart the 'sshd' service and adjust your firewall as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am no friend of SELinux, so this is just a wild guess:
Modify **/etc/services** so that 23/tcp has the same entry as 22/tcp?