# "semanage port" command does not work

Tags: centos, ssh, selinux

So, I was tasked to chagen SSH port in a CentOS server. As I did in the configuration file, the service failed to start, so after a little research I found that I should make some changes in selinux, so it would allow the default port to be changed.

So all I'd have to do is to run the commmand:

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp <port>
```

But when I do, I get the following error:

`Invalid protocol
Bad portcon declaration at /etc/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/100/base/cil:669
OSError: Error`

When I try to run the command

`semanage port -l`

I get the following error:

```
`libsepol.ipproto2sepol: invalid protocol 132 found in policy (No such file or directory).
libsepol.port_to_record: could not convert port range 1 - 511 (???) to record (No such file or directory).
libsepol.sepol_port_iterate: could not iterate over ports (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.dbase_policydb_list: list handler could not extract record (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.dbase_policydb_list: could not list records (No such file or directory).
OSError: No such file or directory`
```

I've download all the necessary packages in order for this to work.

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242717/117549 help?

Comment: No. This is exactly what I tried and is returning the error.

Comment: I didn't see the -m flag in your version...?

Comment: The problem is not with the flag, but with the command itself.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package below and then run the command.

```
yum install policycoreutils-python-utils
```